# Check user exist in active directory group without RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Tags: development, active-directory, runwithelevatedprivileges

Yes I know it is duplicate question of [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25294/how-can-we-differentiate-users-exists-in-particular-group-of-active-directory) and [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60516/how-to-check-if-current-user-is-exist-in-a-ad-group-inside-a-sharepoint-group), but I want to check if user belongs to active directory group **with out** RunWithElevatedPrivileges.
 Is it possible?

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("domain\\groupname");
```

This always returns false. Even if I am in.

I have been googling this for very long.

Is using RunWithElevatedPrivileges affect anything in sharepoint farm level code? If possible please provide any link that refers it is not harmful to use RunWithElevatedPrivileges. Appreciate you help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Elevation of privilege, a feature that was added in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0, enables you to programmatically perform actions in code by using an increased level of privilege. The SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges method enables you to supply a delegate that runs a subset of code in the context of an account with higher privileges than the current user.

> Although elevation of privilege provides a powerful technique for
>   managing security, it should be used with care. You should not expose
>   direct, uncontrolled mechanisms for people with low privileges to
>   circumvent the permissions granted to them.
>   [Elevation of Privilege](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543467(v=office.14).aspx)

If your code run under a farm admin(who is local admin as well) then you dont need this method, but issue is when user does not have the right permission then we need this. It runs using the App Pool account, so you must ensure that the App Pool account is a member of a site collection group with sufficient perms to to add/edit/delete or whatever your code is trying to do.

So their is always risk involve with it.Here are some points to follow while working with RunWithElevatedPrivileges.

- Avoid using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges to access the
  SharePoint object model. Instead, use SPUserToken to impersonate
  SPSite with a specific account, as shown previously.
- If you do use SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges, dispose of all objects in the delegate. Do not pass SharePoint objects out of the RunWithElevatedPrivileges method.
- Only use SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges to make network calls under the application pool identity. Don’t use it for elevation of privilege of SharePoint objects.

http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/runwithelevatedprivileges-in-sharepoint-2010-238.aspx

[When and How to Use Run With Elevated Privileges (RWEP) in SharePoint](http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1022)

Comment: Excellent! Just to clarify -  what about getting users active directory groups using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivilege? As you said "use it to make network calls under the application pool identity". There would not be any security harm in touch AD right?

Comment: I think it is safe as well if use in your code block and follow the tips mentioned above. why not you directly get the information from AD directly, as mentioned in one of the anwser? https://arunjameskc.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/checking-permission-of-spuser-who-is-member-of-an-active-directory-group-which-is-added-to-an-spgroup/

Comment: Your link saved me and directed me to the correct path - 'SPGroup.ContainsCurrentUser' does the trick. Actually this is exact thing I am looking for - http://cosmicice.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-find-user-spuser-or-domain-user.html

Comment: Glad to solve your problem